# How to show a Views attachment in other region or create a block acting as attachment?

Tags: 7, views

I have a view with two displays: *page* and *attachment*. The exposed filters are the same for both the displays, and I used the *Inherit exposed filters* in the attachment settings.

I want to put the attachment in a specific theme region. How can I print the attachment in a different region?

> [image]

The "pink" box is the attachment, which contains a Leaflet map. The user can select either one of the filters and see the results in the box map and the page below (node1, node2, node3, ...).

This is a screenshot of the view page as it is now.

> [image: This is what i have now]

Either of these solutions could work for me:

- Be able to display the attachment display in another region, then the
  page display under it
- Have a block that functions in the same way as an attachment and
  inherits all exposed and contextual filters in the way an attachment
  would do

I tried to use `views_embed_view()` in a custom PHP block. The block shows correctly the attachment, but the filter doesn't work with the new block.

```
$view_name = 'indoor';
$display_id = 'attachment_1';
print views_embed_view($view_name, $display_id);
```

I think the problem is the AJAX parameter *view_dom_id* passed to the block.

This is what i want:

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

At moment I fixed with [contextual filter query](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_contextual_filter_query) by disabling the ajax and get query from URL. This way I can use separated block for the map.